# How to commit the difference between two branches into a third branch?

Tags: git, merge, diff, repo

I've done some hard work recently on a stale branch (say `B`) that has been initially forked from another stale branch (say `A`). `A` has been even deleted from the remote repo, but fortunately I still have a local copy.

Since, I don't want to lose my work, I want to commit to the difference between `A` and `B` into `master`. Please note that squashing and cherry-picking is almost impossible for that there are plenty of commits and I had a lot of merge and conflict resolution all through the road.

From my point of view, and based on my deep understanding, the only way (or say the easiest way) is to compare `A` and `B` (maybe through `git diff B A`) and commit the difference into a new branch (say `C`), then merge `C` into `master`.

**How to commit the difference between two branches into a third branch?**

Comment: It's not clear you need to do anything except merge B into master. If B forked from A, then the entire history of A (up to the point where you forked) is part of B, whether or not A still exists.

Comment: @chepner, but there is a massive difference between B and master (not only my work). A big efforts has been done there, that was due to the fact that A has a enormous difference with master.

Comment: You might also try rebasing B onto master. This may eliminate changes from A.

Comment: Yes, but the difference between B and master *includes* whatever differences existed between A and master when you first created B.

Comment: @isherwood, you're right, this would be the very straightforward solution. The only problem is that I already merged A into B several times.

Comment: Then you may well be in for some manual change migration. I'd use a diff visualizer and start plucking at code. Good luck.

Comment: It's difficult to say precisely what you should do without some picture of what your history looks like. Even an edited/condensed version of `git --graph --oneline A B master` would help.

Comment: Carefully pick two commits, compare them with `git diff` and create a patch, apply the patch on `master` with `git apply -3 $patch`. There could be conflicts. Resolve them if any. I think the difficulty is to decide which two commits to compare.

Comment: @ElpieKay, right! That would be the best solution. The only problem is in case of an existing conflict between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in my solution (thanks ChatGPT for helping out), perhaps it helps someone in the future. The solution was as follows:

1. Checkout to `A`: `git checkout A`
2. Create new branch `C` starting from `A`: `git checkout -b C`
3. Merge `B` into `C`: `git merge B`.
4. Resolve conflicts if any.
5. Stage the changes: `git add .`
6. Commit the staged changes `git commit -m "difference between B and A"`

--- > At this point, all the differences between `A` and `B` are collected into one commit (and even conflicts resolved). Assume that the new commit has a hash `YYYYYYYY`.

7. Now, we `cherry-pick` that commit into `master`: `git cherry-pick -m 1 YYYYYYYY`

Some steps can be simplified but prefer to put the extensive solution.

Comment: I don't see what C is for. In fact I don't really see how this differs from standard reverse merge followed by merge.

Comment: As for the first part, you're right @matt. That's why I added the last comment: "Some steps can be simplified but prefer to put the extensive solution". C makes no sense for my own solution. But I was taking the long way to avoid committing to A, just I don't want to mess up some newbie's branch.

Comment: As for the second part, since A has enormous conflicts with master. In this way, I avoided resolving those conflicts. I just cherry-picked the difference.

Comment: Makes no sense. Cherry picking can and often does give merge conflicts.

Comment: Then reread my comment. I didn't say "to avoid resolving conflicts", but rather to avoid "resolving those conflicts" referring to the conflicts between A and master that are in hundreds.

Comment: Handling the conflict in the reverse merge pre-empts conflicts in the forward merge. It's great that you found an approach that you like, but the question/answer pair remains not useful due to lack of accuracy / sufficient info. Stack Overflow is a public encyclopedia in QA form, not anyone's personal blog of triumphs.

Comment: So now reread my question then: "How to commit the difference between two branches into a third branch?". The story telling part is just to give more context, one can neglect it.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your working directory has no changes.

Then create a branchC at the tip of branchB:

```
git checkout -b branchC branchB
```

Reset **soft** to branchA to get the changes made in B since A:

```
git reset --soft branchA
```

Then commit all the changes.

After that you have in branchC one commit containing all the changes made between A and B. You could then cherry-pick it or use `git rebase --onto` to rebase branchC only commit wherever you want.